# When should I use "remote/branch-name" vs "remote branch-name" in git commands?

Tags: git

When should I use "remote/branch-name" vs "remote branch-name" in git commands?

Sometimes I find commands need "remote/branch-name", other times I find they need "remote branch-name".

I always forget when to use each - is there a rule I can memorize?

Comment: It's not remote/repo but it's often remote/branchname for a "remote-tracking branch".  In fact, it's *almost always* remote/branchname.  The `git pull` command messes with this pattern, so don't use `git pull`—split it up into `git fetch` followed by either `git merge` or `git rebase`—and then it's always instead of almost-always.

Comment: @torek I think this should go as an answer

Comment: @RabeaAbdelWahab: a proper answer takes more space, I think, and this ground has been covered pretty well before.  The root of the problem is that `git pull` goes back to before Git version 1.5, and still supports and uses the old way, before remote-tracking branches existed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that git receives its arguments from the command shell, and the shell produces the list of positional parameters (mostly, depending on your shell) via simple word splitting.

The slash character isn’t any sort of git operator. There are possibly different objects named `master` and `origin/master`, for example. The slash in the name reveals an implementation detail. Go spelunking in `.git/refs` some time.

To push your latest updates to the master branch, you’d run

```
git push origin master
```

Running `git push origin/master` wouldn’t even make sense because the argument in that position is supposed to name a remote. Now, you could do something bizarre like

```
git remote add origin/master git@foo.com.invalid:bar/baz/quux.git
```

to make it sort of “make sense,” but you’ll confuse yourself and may stop being invited to parties. Don’t do that.

Refer to the remote with its bare name. Tracking branches have names of the form `remote/branch`. To rebase against the latest master, you could checkout master, pull, switch back to your branch and rebase. Cut out a couple of steps by referring to the tracking branch directly, *e.g.*,

```
$ git fetch
$ git rebase origin/master
```

Comment: This contradicts torek's comment above where he indicates that there was an evolution of syntax. Your answer suggests that the two syntaxes remain for good reason.